# Cannot parse string API data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, dom, github

I'm trying to access the tags_url returned from the GitHub API, but because typeof = string I need to parse it in order to access it. I'm testing this in the console and receiving the following error message, but I can't understand why.

```
//Returned data:
https://api.github.com/repos/open-guides/og-aws/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/mitchellh/goamz/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/aws/aws-cli/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/pyduan/amazonaccess/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/goamz/goamz/tags
main.js:33 https://api.github.com/repos/voldemort/voldemort/tags

console.log(JSON.parse(dataArr[0].tags_url));

VM1032:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:18
```

Comment: As I can see the `tags_url` is just a normal string and you can access it without parsing, because its not a stringified object.

Comment: It's a normal string, but if I click on it it returns an object, of which the first key I need to access. This key is called name, but because it's a string I can't use tags_url.name or similar, so I'm trying to find a way to access the properties within the string, and parsing seems to be the only way (only that it's not stringified, like you said)